# In what formal proof systems is the deduction theorem taken as a primitive rule of inference?

Tags: logic, proof-theory

Wikipedia's [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem) on the deduction theorem states:

> Although the deduction theorem could be taken as primitive rule of inference in [Hilbert-style] systems, this approach is not generally followed; instead, the deduction theorem is obtained as an admissible rule using the other logical axioms and modus ponens. In other formal proof systems, the deduction theorem is sometimes taken as a primitive rule of inference.

The article then cites natural deduction as an example of the latter case.

So I am wondering: in what other formal proof systems, besides natural deduction, is the deduction theorem taken as a primitive rule of inference?

EDIT: In particular, I am interested in *Hilbert-like* systems for which this is the case (or any formal proof system that, in general, prefers axioms over rules of inference, with the exception of using the deduction theorem rather than, e.g., Łukasiewicz's axioms *CpCqp* and *CCpCqrCCpqCpr*).

Comment: does it really make some difference that it is a primitive rule or the composition of $2$ or $3$ primitive rules ?

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, because if the deduction theorem is taken as a primitive rule, then the axioms of positive implicational logic become superfluous.

Comment: Of course, in Gentzen's [sequent calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus) **LK**: $\to$-R.

Comment: This part of wikipedia got wrote poorly.  In natural deduction systems, you don't have a rule of inference called the deduction theorem.  You have a rule of inference which says "from $\gamma$ U {A} $\vdash$ B, you may infer $\gamma$ $\vdash$ (A -> B)," which can get called conditional introduction.  The deduction (meta) theorem consists of an if ... then *statement* about propositions.  Thus, you have to use modus ponens to apply the deduction theorem *and* modus ponens.

Comment: Additionally, even if the terminology here was not so poor, if say the rule of conditional introduction got taken as a primitive rule of inference in a Hilbert System with modus ponens and appropriate axioms such as (in Polish notation), CpCqp, CCpCqrCCpqCpr, then the rule of conditional introduction becomes derivable in that system.  Addiitonally, CpCqp, and CCpCqrCCpqCpr stand as derivable from just the rule of conditional introduction and modus ponens (which is needed to prove the deduction theorem).  Thus, independence of rules and axioms doesn't hold.

Comment: And having dependent axioms or rules of inference violates the principle of parsimony, or "Occam's Razor".  As long as simpler theories should get preferred in their foundations, that implies that what Wikipedia suggests to do shouldn't get done.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood taking the deduction theorem as a primitive rule of inference in a Hilbert System could potentially allow one to _eliminate_ the axioms CpCqp and CCpCqrCCpqCpr, so no dependencies would occur. That would be the goal.

Comment: @HansBrende There's a little more to it.  In Hilbert-Frege systems we have a rule of uniform substitution (or we can use substitution instances of any axiom or theorem).  If you have conditional introduction as primitive rule of inference in a Hilbert-Frege context, you need to re-formulate that rule, because you can't use the rule of uniform substitution on any formula in a derivation which starts with a hypothesis which gets discharged.  From another perspective, the variables in something like p, Cpq, $\vdash$ q, differ from those in CpCCpqq.

Comment: In something like CpCCpqq, we can extend propositonal calculus by writing something like $\forall$p$\forall$q CpCCpqq.  And thus we can use universal quantifiers over an entire formula.  But, we can't do this in something like p, Cpq $\vdash$ q.  Use of the rule of conditional introduction can pass from p, Cpq $\vdash$ q to CpCCpqq, but the use of that rule completely misses the distinction between the variables between those two things.  There also Hilbert-Frege systems with functorial variables, but if conditional introduction gets taken on a priori, that sort of extension isn't so happy.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Any rules of inference that must be reformulated to accommodate the deduction theorem as a primitive rule of inference is fine with me! I'm merely asking which, if any, Hilbert-like systems are successful in this reformulation. Judging by wikipedia's [example of one such reformulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem#Virtual_rules_of_inference), I doubt this is impossible.